# How to add a caption to a picture which already fills out the whole frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, captions

In my slideshow, I have a picture which needs a caption but for better looking I want it to be in the original ratio. Therefore the size of the image is defined as `width=\pagewidth` and `height=\pageheight`. How do I add a caption which is shown on the image itself, for example in the upper right corner.

MMW of the frame with the image

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{default}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% absolute positioning of typeset material    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[4][center]{%
    % [#1]: box anchor: center (default) | 
    %                 south west | west | north west | north |
    %                 north east | east | south east | south | 
    %                 mid west | mid | mid east |
    %                 base west | base | base east 
    % #2: horizontal position (fraction of page width)
    % #3: vertical position (fraction of page height)
    % #4: content
    %
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]{%
        \node[anchor=#1,inner sep=0pt]
        at ($(current page.south west)+(#2,#3)$) {#4};
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\begin{frame}{}
\placetextbox[south]{0.5}{0}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{IMG_7917.jpg}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to use an actual caption (`\captionof{figure}`), put it inside a minipage `{\linewidth}`.  The height adjustment is a bit trickier since bearmer doesn't know how bit the trame is until later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{default}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){Some text about ducks.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to center the text?

Comment: @mugdi `\node at (current page.center){Some text about ducks.};` or `\node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){Some text about ducks.};`.